# xpce prolog consult program

Tags: prolog, xpce

in this url http://www.commonkads.uva.nl/frameset-commonkads.html
on tools tab there is an example program in prolog
i download it and consult main_xpce but no window appear to show program
this is a xpce prolog program and must have a window

i have similar problem with demo xpce in swi that they are act like that ,when consult no windows appear!
for example kangaroo.pl in C:\Program Files (x86)\swipl\xpce\prolog\demo
when consult this file no appearance results
but when use xpce.man menu it work properly
plz help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ck-prolog seems working... but I don't know what's expected.

I downloaded ck-prolog.zip, unzipped, loaded main_pce.pl, and run

```
?- [main_pce].
%   auxilliary compiled 0.01 sec, 33 clauses
%   oo_kernel compiled 0.01 sec, 31 clauses
%   ck_kernel compiled 0.02 sec, 116 clauses
%   inf_methods compiled 0.00 sec, 14 clauses
%  architecture compiled 0.04 sec, 203 clauses
%  views_pce compiled 0.00 sec, 9 clauses
%  controller compiled 0.00 sec, 24 clauses
%  model compiled 0.04 sec, 256 clauses
%  database compiled 0.00 sec, 2 clauses
% main_pce compiled 0.10 sec, 506 clauses
true.

?- go.
```

after some sec I get a window with 3 panels, then after 3 clicks I get

[image]

I'm sorry I don't know what that means...

Comment: i'm so novice in xpce and prolog idon't know it's need to type "go" for executing.thank you sir...it's very kind of you.